# How to query on current date and bring back objects in Realm that contains it?

Tags: android, database, date, realm

So working on a android app using the realm database. I can  find out the current date, which I can do using Calendar.getInstance(), but what I want to know is how I can use a realm model to actually store different weekdays for a object.

My model looks like this:

```
public class Habit extends RealmObject{
private static int id=0;
private String name;
private Date created;
private ArrayList<Date> repeat;
private Date updated;
private Date reminder;
private int target;
private int tracker;
// getter and setters 
}
```

I am trying to store the days that would be repeating (so max 7 or daily, and at least 1 as minimum) in the ArrayList of repeat since Realm doesn't accept Calendar.

I would create the object and then pass in the appropriate data to fill in the fields and based on the number of days selected send those date objects as well (for example Repeat on Monday, Tuesday, Friday). I would then query on the realm db to bring back all objects that contain the current date gotten by the calendar.getInstance(). At least this is what I was thinking.

The problem however is that at the moment I am taking a string input to determine which days the user wants the item to repeat, how do i translate this to a date item that is the weekday/weekend and then store it in my realm object?

Any help or suggestions would really help in getting this to work. Also if any extra code would help let me know what I can add.

Thank you.

Comment: Slighly offtopic, but your id probably shouldn't be static.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  private ArrayList<Date> repeat;
> ```

Realm does not support list of primitives, and Date is considered a primitive.

You need to create a class-specific object that has a Date parameter.

```
public class Habit extends RealmObject{
    private static int id=0;
    private String name;
    private Date created;
    private RealmList<HabitDate> repeat;
    private Date updated;
    private Date reminder;
    private int target;
    private int tracker;
    // getter and setters 
}

public class HabitDate extends RealmObject {
    private Date date;

    private Habit habit; // <-- because query across `@LinkingObjects` is 3.3+
}
```